# if $a = 3 and $b = 100 so i can get how many has been minused from $b=100 in $c variable (eg.$c = 3) in php.?

Tags: php

if $a = 3 and $b = 100 so i can get how many has been minused from $b=100 in $c variable (eg.$c = 3) in php.?
I just need minused number from the addition of two variable 3 and 100
answer should be 3 in my third variable.

Comment: That is matematical, but there are a few things you need to clear up in order to provide you with the solution.
Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Do you just want to find the lowest of the 2 variables? So you could say `$c = $a; if ($b < $c) $c = $b;`

Comment: `$c = min([$a, $b]);`

Comment: sir i just wanted to if im done subtraction between two number so how many value been minus from those two subtraction just that i want in variable $c.

Comment: _“from those two subtraction”_ - oh now there’s two of them already? Still no clue what you are trying to ask here, or what you actually want.

Comment: There's no addition or subtraction you can do involving `100` and `3` that results in `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go look up the math operators for php there is a lot of docs for that

```
$c = $b - $a
```

then variable c will be equal to 97

Comment: OP wants `$c = 3`

Comment: Why is $a = 3 sound like he wants to know what the value is when subtracting $a from $b

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" =)

Comment: sir i just wanted to if im done subtraction between two number so how many value been minus from those two subtraction just that i want in variable $c.